a sequence of characteristic functions converge uniformly near t=0, then they are equicontinuous
I encountered a problem when reading A course in probability theory by Kailai Chung:

If the sequence of ch.f.'s $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly in a neighborhood of the origin, then $\{f_n\}$ is equicontinuous, and there exists a subsequence that converges to a ch.f. [HINT: Use Ascoli-Arzela's theorem.]

I tried to estimate as follows:
$|f_n(t)-f_n(s)| \le |f_n(t)-f(t)| + |f(t)-f(s)| + |f(s)-f_n(s)|$, where $f$ denotes what $\{f_n\}$ converges into. The first and the third items can be controlled when $n$ is large enough by the uniformly convergence. But I have no idea about the properties of $f$.
The approach above also has another problem, as we only have information in a small neighborhood near $0$.
I know the main reason I cannot figure it out is that I haven't use any properties of characteristic functions. But how? Eagerly anticipating any assistance.

See Probability by Billingsley, for example.

The answer is hidden in Kailai Chung's book. The only difficulty lies in the proof of equicontinuity. Then Arzela-Ascoli theorem and Thm 6.3.2 can be directly used to prove the latter statement.
First we demonstrate the limit function of {$f_n$} is continuous in the neighborhood, say $B(0,\delta_{0})$:
$$
\left|f(x+\delta)-f(x)\right|\leq\left|f_n(x+\delta)-f(x+\delta)\right|+\left|f_n(x+\delta)-f_n(x)\right|+\left|f_n(x)-f(x)\right|<3\cdot\frac{\varepsilon}{3}=\varepsilon
$$
in which uniform convergence and uniform continuity of ch.f.'s are used.
Now we have the estimate, conducted the same as Thm 6.3.2:
$$
\mu_{n}([-2\delta^{-1},2\delta^{-1}])\geq 2(1-\varepsilon)-1\geq 1-2\varepsilon
$$
for any given $\varepsilon >0$, $0<\delta=\delta(\varepsilon)<\delta_{0}$, and $n\geq n_{0}=n_{0}(\varepsilon)$.
Then we can do the estimate (Thm 6.3.1):
$$
\left|f_{n}(t+h)-f_{n}(t)\right|\leq\int\left|e^{ihx}-1\right|\mu_{n}(\mathrm{d}x)\leq\int_{|x|\leq 2\delta^{-1}}|hx|\mu_{n}(\mathrm{d}x)+2\int_{|x|>2\delta^{-1}}\mu_{n}(\mathrm{d}x)\leq|h|\cdot2\delta^{-1}+4\varepsilon
$$
Setting $|h|\leq\varepsilon\delta$, equicontinuity follows.

Many thanks. I think the key is the "uniform tightness", that the seq. of p.m. ${\mu_n}$ decays uniformly outside $[-n, n]$ when $n$ tending to infinity.

@Puppet You've got it :-)
